# how to change domain of computer in many computer in all of our company?

Tags: networking, active-directory

I would like to change `abc` domain to `def` domain for all computers on my network.

How do I change them all on the network and backup?

My server is Windows Server 2003 and it is used as an Active Directory and domain controller.

(Also, what about software that can be used in Active Directory?)

Comment: So, are we talking about AD? Normal DNS? What?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have a very good business case for doing this... if you have applications in your environment that depend on Active Directory, they will likely break.  If you have Exchange 2003, it requires you to run a fix-up tool afterwards.  You cannot do it if you have Exchange 2007 or 2010 in your environment.  MOM/Operations Manager will need to be uninstalled before the domain rename and reinstalled afterwards.  SQL connection strings will need to be updated manually  (those are just off the top of my head).  You will need to test everything in a lab so that you find out what will/will not work in your own environment.

If, after all that, you decide to proceed... here is how to do it:

**Windows Server 2003 Active Directory Domain Rename Tools & Documentation**
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/downloads/winsrvr/domainrename.mspx

**How Domain Rename Works**
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738208(WS.10).aspx and here: 
**Introduction to Administering Active Directory Domain Rename**
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816848(WS.10).aspx

**Checklists for the Domain Rename Operation**

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816631(WS.10).aspx.

Webcasts

**TechNet Support WebCast: Renaming domains when Microsoft Exchange Server 2003 is 
in the Active Directory**
http://support.microsoft.com/?id=838623

**Support WebCast: Microsoft Windows Server 2003: Implementing an Active Directory 
Domain Rename Operation**
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;819145

Another option would be to create a new domain and migrate over the users and computers using ADMT (guide here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc974332(WS.10).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

do you mean rename an Active Directory domain?

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=292541

or maybe
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/windowsserver/bb405948.aspx

I think you need to elaborate a little more.  Although my powers of mental telepathy have improved since I first started answering questions on serverfault, they're not that good.

Answer (score 0):

Or us the Active Directory Migration Tool if you prefer the GUI.

Comment: That would work, but would require him to setup a new domain before migrating the computers from one domain to the other.

Comment: It would yes, but isn't that exactly what he's asking? How could/why would he migrate to a domain that doesn't yet exist?

Answer (score -1):

Use good network management software

Comment: Good network management software will not rename a domain

Answer (score -1):

you can script this using netdom.exe

```
NETDOM /Domain:def /user:adminuser /password:apassword MEMBER
      MYCOMPUTER /JOINDOMAIN
```

Comment: He's not asking how to join a domain, he wants to change his domain name (which is much more complicated)